# Trying to update workday human resources web service

Tags: c#, web-services, workday-api

We have C# application running in prod, which updates `email`, `emplid` and `other id` in the workday. Requirements change, and we have to modify the code not to update `email` and only the `emplid` and `other id`. I brought back  the code and commented on the part updating the `email`. I also update the workday Human Resources Service version (40.2) as I have to do testing before releasing it to prod. I am getting error:

> Validation error occurred. Invalid Subelement
> Worker_Reference-urn:com.workday/bsvc for element
> Change_Other_IDs_Business_Process_Data.

I don't know what this means. I did research online and tried to find the answer but could not figure it out. I am a newbie to C# and web services. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Error message:

> Validation error occurred. Invalid Subelement
> Worker_Reference-urn:com.workday/bsvc for element
> Change_Other_IDs_Business_Process_Data.

Comment: We need to see actual C# code to help you with this this. 
But it appears an event isn't working as intended. 

"Invalid sub-element" likely means a child object on a parent is missing, or doesn't conform to a schema, and thus is invalid. 

So you have to check for null, and check that data is within expected parameters, that should fix it

Answer (score 0):

Check down the list of optional and required elements.

Your Worker Reference element is in the wrong section of the request. Worker Reference lives under the Comment Data Object and is described as "Default the Person making the comment to the processing person if not submitted via the web service". You can still add a comment to the business process, I typically say something like "updated by integration name".

The Person reference object is where you want to put the ID you are updating, described as "A reference to the ID of the person through one of its active person types, such as worker, student, affiliate, external committee member, and so on. The ID consists of a type attribute, which should be set to one of either "Employee_ID", "Contingent_Worker_ID", "Student_ID", etc, and a value attribute, such as "04345"."

[More info about the request, wsdl and xsd are all here](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Human_Resources/v40.2/Change_Other_IDs.html).

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>?</bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>
      </bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bsvc:Change_Other_IDs_Request bsvc:version="?">
         <!--Optional:-->
         <bsvc:Business_Process_Parameters>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bsvc:Auto_Complete>?</bsvc:Auto_Complete>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bsvc:Run_Now>?</bsvc:Run_Now>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bsvc:Comment_Data>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <bsvc:Comment>?</bsvc:Comment>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <bsvc:Worker_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="?">
                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                  <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="?">?</bsvc:ID>
               </bsvc:Worker_Reference>
            </bsvc:Comment_Data>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <bsvc:Business_Process_Attachment_Data>
               <bsvc:File_Name>?</bsvc:File_Name>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <bsvc:Event_Attachment_Description>?</bsvc:Event_Attachment_Description>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <bsvc:Event_Attachment_Category_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="?">
                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                  <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="?">?</bsvc:ID>
               </bsvc:Event_Attachment_Category_Reference>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <bsvc:File>cid:1330440114922</bsvc:File>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <bsvc:Content_Type>?</bsvc:Content_Type>
            </bsvc:Business_Process_Attachment_Data>
         </bsvc:Business_Process_Parameters>
         <bsvc:Change_Other_IDs_Data>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bsvc:Person_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="?">
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="?">?</bsvc:ID>
            </bsvc:Person_Reference>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bsvc:Universal_ID_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="?">
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="?">?</bsvc:ID>
            </bsvc:Universal_ID_Reference>
            <bsvc:Custom_Identification_Data bsvc:Replace_All="?">
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <bsvc:Custom_ID bsvc:Delete="?">
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <bsvc:Custom_ID_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="?">
                     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                     <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="?">?</bsvc:ID>
                  </bsvc:Custom_ID_Reference>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <bsvc:Custom_ID_Data>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <bsvc:ID>?</bsvc:ID>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <bsvc:ID_Type_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="?">
                        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                        <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="?">?</bsvc:ID>
                     </bsvc:ID_Type_Reference>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <bsvc:Issued_Date>?</bsvc:Issued_Date>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <bsvc:Expiration_Date>?</bsvc:Expiration_Date>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <bsvc:Organization_ID_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="?">
                        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                        <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="?">?</bsvc:ID>
                     </bsvc:Organization_ID_Reference>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <bsvc:Custom_Description>?</bsvc:Custom_Description>
                  </bsvc:Custom_ID_Data>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <bsvc:Custom_ID_Shared_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="?">
                     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                     <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="?">?</bsvc:ID>
                  </bsvc:Custom_ID_Shared_Reference>
               </bsvc:Custom_ID>
            </bsvc:Custom_Identification_Data>
         </bsvc:Change_Other_IDs_Data>
      </bsvc:Change_Other_IDs_Request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```